# How to write a test case for Xframe response header

Tags: java, junit, websphere

I wrote a code to resolve cross-frame scripting defect related to one of the servlet. code is as following
utility class

```
public class VulnerabilityUtil {

public final static String INVALID_REQUEST_TYPE_ERROR = "Invalid Request Type.";
public final static String INVALID_USER_ACCESS = "Access Denied!";

/** Missing HTTP X-Frame-Options Response Header **/
public static void setHTTPXFrameResponseHeader(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
}
```

and calling that method from the AddDelegateServlet like

```
VulnerabilityUtil.setHTTPXFrameResponseHeader(response);
```

Now, After searching through internet, I somehow manage to write an test case which is as following

```
@Test 
public void XFrameOptionsTest() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

   CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
   HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:5138/alservlet/AddDelegateServlet");
   HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

   // only for debugging
   System.out.println(request.getRequestLine());
   Header headers[] = response.getAllHeaders();
   for(Header h:headers){
      System.out.println(h.getName() + ": " + h.getValue());
   }

   assertNotNull("X-Frame-Options header used?", response.getFirstHeader("X-Frame-Options"));
   assertTrue("X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN?", "SAMEORIGIN".equals(response.getFirstHeader("X-Frame-Options").getValue()));

}
```

But there are few problems with it

1 - I used apache http client whereas we are using websphere server.

2 - I dont know if websphere have anything similar to apache  http client that I cause to instead of apache's http client.

3 - My test case failed as assertTrue unable to get the header "X-Frame-Options" even though its being set and can be checked by using google developer tools.

response headers

```
  Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, s-maxage=0, must-revalidate, proxy- 
  revalidate, no-store, private
  Content-Language: en-US
  Content-Length: 28951
  Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
  Date: Wed, 22 May 2019 16:08:42 GMT
  Expires: Tue, 04 Dec 1993 21:29:02 GMT
  Pragma: no-cache
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000,includeSubDomains
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0
  X-XSS-Protection: 1
```

I want to know how can I write a successful test case that can resolve all the issues mentioned above.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.